# PHP Require_once and after that call a function

Tags: php, require-once

2 files: resetMyEvent.php and resetEvent.php

In resetMyEvent.php I need to do a require_once for resetEvent.php

path: admin/resetMyEvent.php

and

path: room/server/updateUserInfo/resetEvent.php

1.First question: get error at require_once because the path is not good, why?

2.Second question: and after that how do i call the function in resetEvent.php in require_once with a parameter from try?

--> the parameter is $currentRoom['eventID'];

This is the the code from resetMyEvent.php:

```html
<?php
require_once('security.php');
require_once('../room/server/db/db.php');

//Here is my require 
require_once('../room/server/updateUserInfo/resetEvent.php');

try {
    // Get this subdomain's currentRoom eventId
    $sql = $dbPDO->prepare("SELECT `coupleEventId` AS `eventId` FROM currentRooms WHERE `serverName`=?");
    $sql->execute([$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]);
    $currentRoom = $sql->fetch();
    // Set eventEnd for this eventId back to NULL
    $sql = $dbPDO->prepare("UPDATE couple_events SET `cplEv_eventEnd`=NULL WHERE `cplEv_Id`=?");
    $sql->execute([$currentRoom['eventId']]);
    ////////////////this is the parameter $currentRoom['eventId']
    echo 'Reset eventEnd for Event '.$currentRoom['eventId'];
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Because the path is not valid. For any more insight, share your directory structure. 2. Call it as `whateverFunctionsNameMayBe($currentRoom['eventID')` like any other function.

Comment: 2 directory: admin & room | admin/resetMyEvent.php here i want to do the require with this path room/server/updateUserInfo/resetEvent.php

Comment: OK. And you are certain that the script called is in `/whatever/admin/resetMyEvent.php` (instead of `resetMyEvent.php` being called e.g. from `/whatever/index.php` and the included script is in `room/server/updateUserInfo/resetEvent.php`? Try `__DIR__ . '../room/server ...' to ensure your directory reference is correct. Please also update your post with the exact error message you get.

Comment: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(..room/server/updateUserInfo/resetEvent.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gdobrea/dev4.couple.eu/room-couple-eu/admin/resetMyEvent.php on line 4PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '..room/server/updateUserInfo/resetEvent.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/gdobrea/dev4.couple.eu/room-couple-eu/admin/resetMyEvent.php on line 4', referer: https://dev4.couple.eu/admin/

Comment: Your error says, `require_once(..room/server`. Notice **..room**. That doesn't match with the code you posted, which has **../room**.